# Determining Big O Notation of based on python function

Tags: python, big-o

I have a school assignment where I need to determine the Big O notations of two functions. The problem is we have had no real courses on Big O, let alone Python. Could someone explain how to determine the big-O, given these functions? Thanks!

```
def my_func1(inputs):
    n = len(inputs)
    result = 0
    for i in range(n):
        j = 1
        while j < n:
            result += inputs[i] * inputs[j]
            j *= 2
    return result

def my_func2(inputs):
    n = len(inputs)
    for i in range(n - 1):
        for j in range(n - i - 1):
            if inputs[j] > inputs[j + 1]:
                tmp = inputs[j]
                inputs[j] = inputs[j + 1]
                inputs[j + 1] = tmp
```

Comment: Did you have "not real" courses on "Big O" or Python? I'm sure you do not get such an assignment without having covered this in *any* way before.

Comment: In any case, Stack Overflow is not meant to replace tutorials or teaching. You need to ask a specific question about an actual programming problem you have encountered.

Comment: We have covered some python(My second course with Python), and had one lecture on Big 0 notations. Its just that I am struggling to grasp how to find these functions Big-0 notations. Im not asking for a tutorial or lecture, but any help on finding these functions Big-0 notations.

Comment: You find them by thinking about how many operations the function performs, depending on the number of items in the input.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the Big O Notation for the above functions, you may have to go through the algorithm analysis of Big O Notation.

Big-O notation is a metrics used to find algorithm complexity. Basically, Big-O notation signifies the relationship between the input to the algorithm and the steps required to execute the algorithm. It is denoted by a big "O" followed by opening and closing parenthesis. Inside the parenthesis, the relationship between the input and the steps taken by the algorithm is presented using "n".

Let's write a simple algorithm in Python that finds the square of the first item in the list and then prints it on the screen.

```
def constant_algo(items):
    result = items[0] * items[0]
    print ()

constant_algo([4, 5, 6, 8])
```

In the above script, irrespective of the input size, or the number of items in the input list items, the algorithm performs only 2 steps: Finding the square of the first element and printing the result on the screen. Hence, the complexity remains constant. In Big O Notation, it is O(C).

Same way, we can simply find the Big O Notations for the algorithms or code by going through [this](https://stackabuse.com/big-o-notation-and-algorithm-analysis-with-python-examples/) documentation.
The Big O Notations for the above two functions is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

**my_func1**
Here the outer for loop is linear in input size, whereas the inner while loop has an order of growth which is logarithmic in input size n as variable j doubles in each iteration, both loop combined gives you a time complexity of nlogn

**my_func2**
This looks like bubble sort with a time complexity of n^2